# override css style by another css style in gwt

Tags: css, gwt

I need to override css style for a particular element with another css file's style in gwt.

I have tried by the following code

```
    sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");
    Window.alert("test");
    sendButton.addStyleName("butt");
```

The alert is coming. but the style has not been overridden. the css code is
        .sendButton {
             display: block;
             font-size: 16pt;
             color:red;
         }
          .butt{
             font-size:32pt;
             visible:false;
             color:green;
          }
the button font is in red colour only it is not changed to green. i have included this css in html file as well.

so please tell me how to override one css style by another css file's style in gwt.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");
 Window.alert("test");
 sendButton.setStyleName("butt");
```

setStyleName Clears all of the object's style names and sets it to the given style.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the setStyleName and added as addStyleName() method. It is useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the style that you want applied to all buttons, you can override the style the GWT applies to all buttons: `gwt-Button`.

Alternatively, try:

```
color: red !important;
```

or be more specific with your CSS selector so that other CSS rules do not take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it is useful to me. I put the style with !important in css

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the .gwt-button and .gwt-Button-selected are the default style names(provided by GWT) of you button.

You can do sth like below. Here I have removed some css properties(all properties are random here). You should write these css properties in your UIBinder.

```
@external .gwt-Button;
    .gwt-Button {
      cursor: pointer;
      cursor: hand;
      color: #3e3e3e;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      background: white;
      margin-top: -6px;
      margin-top: -33px;
      margin-left: -1px;
    }
    @external .gwt-Button-selected;
    .gwt-Button .gwt-Button-selected {
      cursor: default;
      background: white;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.